# Store Power Query custom function Online (Github etc..,) and call it

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

**Main Question :**

I have created various custom functions that I frequently use. I would like to store them in a repository somewhere and call them whenever necessary. I know that I can save all those functions in an Excel file and save it in OneDrive. But I would like to save them somewhere I can edit and share them easily like GitHub.

And finally, if it is possible, can we make a private repository? If i want few of my functions to be shared privately, can I protect/lock them using a password?

**Helpful Resources:**

> Understanding the following probably might be helpful in answering this.

**Resource 1:**

There is a function called `#shared` in PowerQuery which lists down all the functions available and their respective description. You can know more about it at the [following post](https://radacad.com/power-query-library-of-functions-shared-keyword).

I think understanding how does this function (#shared) work and Where is this information being extracted from will be helpful in answering My main question above. Which is basically, **how can I make something like this for my custom functions?**

**Resource 2:**

One possible help for this question would be an [existing repository](https://github.com/Hugoberry/PowerQuery) in Github by Hugoberry.

**Note:**

1. I'm not a coder, but I'm comfortable in reading/understanding codes.
2. I don't understand Github very clearly.

## Edit 1:

For those who are looking for an answer to this question, the [answer provided by Nacho](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57298100/6908282) works for creating a function with **Manual Entry(Text/Number)** inputs.

It **does not work** for functions that refer to a table/parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After taking a long path on this I solved it. Below are the steps to do this:

1. First create a .pq file with Notepad like this example and push it to GitHub:

```
let
    TextAsNumber = (valor as number)  => 
        let
            Mostra = "The number is: " & Text.From(valor)
        in

    Mostra
in
    TextAsNumber
```

2. Then go to the file in github and click on "Raw"
   [image: GitHub - Raw]
3. Copy the URL. Open Power Bi Desktop edit queries. Get Data from blank query and paste this:

```
= Expression.Evaluate(Text.FromBinary(Web.Contents("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ibarrau/PowerBi-code/master/PowerQuery/PQFun.pq")),#shared)
```

4. That code will create you the function from repository.

**Note:** The same thing can be made with local path too, just replace Web by File on "Contents". Like so:

```
= Expression.Evaluate(Text.FromBinary(File.Contents("C:\Users\username\Documents\Folder\Sub-Folder\PQFun.pq")),#shared)
```

Hope this helps you to manage better the custom function repository.

PS: I'm not sure if you are going to be able to refresh in Service.

Comment: Thank you @Nacho. Looks like this does work for functions which need **Manual entry (Number/Text)**. But I would like to know if its possible for functions referring to **Tables**

Comment: @Nacho, can you let me know if its possible to use this workflow with a private repository?

Comment: The function run any code in a text string. It will work with a function or a table. The thing is that function is not allowed in power bi service.
About private repository I don't se why that shouldn't work. It will be the same as configuring the authentication for other source.